# In Visual Studio, how can I change/disable the line-highlight color when I double-click on a row in "Find Results"?

Tags: search, colors, highlight

Sorry for the complicated title.

Screenshot here:

[image: screenshot]

Basically:

- Do a "Find in Files" search in VS.
- Double click on one of the results.
- The line in the editor window is highlighted with dark blue (in my case).
- The highlight does not go away unless I do another "Find in Files" search and click on another result.

The problems:

- The highlight is too dark/overpowering.
- I can't see other highlights (like selecting text, or even where my cursor is).
- I want the highlight to go away while I'm editing the file.

So my questions:

- Can I change the color of this highlight to something less powerful? (a nice light gray perhaps)  I can't seem to tell which of the color-coding options changes this one.
- Can I clear this highlight somehow while editing (without needing to do another search)
- Can I disable this highlighting completely?

Thanks!

PS. I'm not interested in the line-highlight color in the "Find Results" window itself - just the highlight that appears in my text-editor window after I double-click on one of the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your color settings.

Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors

Select "Show settings for: Find Results Window" and change the "Current List Location" background color.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Isn't it possible to disable the Current List Location entirely? With this I can make it less noticeable, but all the text has the same color which is overriding the normal syntax highlighting

Comment: For me, I had to change `Current List Location` in the `Text Editor` section, not in `Find Results Window`